# Form with nested controllers and "controller as" syntax

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to create a more than average complex form with custom actions on some controls. The main controller of the view is holding the model that will be saved at the end. Inside this main controller, I have a separate controller for each input control that has some specific actions.

Here is a short example and the question is, if I want to implement the `UserChoiceCtrl.selectLastUser` function, how can I do without using `$scope` ?

More generally, **how can I access to a model in the main controller in a child controller** ? It's easy in the view, but how can I do in the controller code ?

[@Plunker if you prefer](http://plnkr.co/edit/WKtTcGCUDe0Suro9VHDE?p=preview)

```js
angular.module('myApp', []);

angular.module('myApp')
  .controller('TaskCtrl', [
    function() {
      var viewModel = this;

      // This is injected in controller in real life
      viewModel.users = [
        {login: 'Tom', password: '123'}, 
        {login: 'Stanley', password: '123'}, 
        {login: 'Joe', password: '123'}, 
        {login: 'Katy', password: '123'},
        {login: 'Kate', password: '123'},
        {login: 'Tony', password: '123'}
      ];

      viewModel.task = {
        user: viewModel.users[0],
        description: ''
      };

      viewModel.save = function() {
        alert(angular.toJson(viewModel.task));
      };
    }
  ]);

angular.module('myApp')
  .controller('UserChoiceCtrl', [
    function() {
      var viewModel = this;

      viewModel.selectLastUser = function() {
        // No way to access the task variable @ TaskCtrl ?

        // The following line is working but using $scope
        // $scope.taskCtrl.task.user = $scope.taskCtrl.users[5];
      };
    }
  ]);
```

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Arial';
}
label,
input,
textarea {
  display: block;
}
label {
  margin-top: 8px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html data-ng-app="myApp">

<head>
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.0" data-semver="1.4.0" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.0/angular.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body data-ng-controller="TaskCtrl as taskCtrl">
  <h1>New task</h1>
  <form name="taskCtrl.taskForm">
    <label>Description</label>
    <textarea data-ng-model="taskCtrl.task.description"></textarea>
    <div data-ng-controller="UserChoiceCtrl as userChoiceCtrl">
      <label>User</label>
      <select data-ng-model="taskCtrl.task.user" data-ng-options="user as user.login for user in taskCtrl.users"></select>
      <button data-ng-click="userChoiceCtrl.selectLastUser()">Last user of list</button>
    </div>
    <br>
    <button data-ng-click="taskCtrl.save()">Save</button>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: just pass in this function from view like `userChoiceCtrl.selectLastUser(taskCtrl.users)`, another way - use service or factory for saving data

Comment: but why you don't want use _$scope_?

Comment: @Grundy $scope is considered by the core angular team as an anti-practice now, since it's not even a concept in angular 2.0.  They still support the syntax because of it's wide use, but recommend using ControllerAs syntax as a first step in forward compatibility with angular 2.0, and switching to ControllerAs is the first step in migrating legacy code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<button data-ng-click="userChoiceCtrl.selectLastUser(taskCtrl.task.user)">Last user of list</button>

 viewModel.selectLastUser = function(user) {
        alert(user);
        // No way to access the task variable @ TaskCtrl ?

        // The following line is working but using $scope
        // $scope.taskCtrl.task.user = $scope.taskCtrl.users[5];
   };
```

Comment: For now, this is the closest to what I am looking for.

Comment: I will just wait a bit to see if some other better idea come up, then if nothing better, I will accept your answer.

Comment: This is the exact answer for your question

Answer (score 1):

A way could be creating the main controller as a service and injecting it to the children:
http://fdietz.github.io/recipes-with-angular-js/controllers/sharing-code-between-controllers-using-services.html

Comment: Injecting a service to get the user list or a specific user in any controller is a nice idea, but I still can't change the `taskCtrl.task.user` value from `userChoiceCtrl`.

Answer (score 0):

See if this serves the purpose,
 basically i am getting an instance of the task controller using the $controller service.

```
angular.module('myApp')
  .controller('UserChoiceCtrl', function ($controller) {
      var task = $controller('TaskCtrl');
      console.log("Task", task);
      var viewModel = this;

      viewModel.selectLastUser = function () {
           // No way to access the task variable @ TaskCtrl ?

           // The following line is working but using $scope
           // $scope.taskCtrl.task.user = $scope.taskCtrl.users[5];
           task.task.user = task.users[5];
           alert ( task.task.user.login);
     };
     console.log("User", viewModel)
  });
```

Comment: I've tried and it seems to create a new instance of the controller every time `$controller('TaskCtrl')` is used.